# Can we empower low-rep users with elevated privileges given that they have demonstrable moderating ability and know-how of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation, privileges, gamification

My biggest pet peeve about Stack Overflow's Gamification system is that it gives moderation privileges (which don't need any or very little technical knowledge) to people who have technical knowledge regardless of if they know anything about moderation.

You could have never edited someone else's post in your life and you would be given the privilege to instantly apply edits given that you have enough knowledge about some technical topic that has absolutely nothing to do with editing posts.

On the other side of the coin you could have edited hundreds of thousands of posts, participated in numerous reviews, have been active every single day on Meta for years on end but if you don't have enough technical knowledge you are neither getting any appreciation nor any privilege for all that you have done for this site.

One example of such a low rep user that comes to my mind is [Jeanne Dark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11682469/jeanne-dark?tab=profile) who has ~1k rep, has answered 8 times and has 0 questions but has cast 70,052 votes, raised 24,724 helpful flags, has 3 Steward badges, is very active on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Participation&filter=all), SOCVR and other chat rooms and has a lot of knowledge about Stack Overflow's workings.

---

An idea that has been on my mind for months now was to allow low-rep user with **exceptional** participation in the moderation effort and with a good track record of participation on meta to receive higher privileges without having enough reputation.

You know... like moderators/staff. They could have a symbol like the moderator diamond ♦ (a spade symbol maybe ♠) and could be designated with some title to avoid confusion ("elevated user" probably ¯\_(ツ)_/¯).

My idea was that these privileges could be given either automatically (say after crossing a certain threshold of number of actions, like the 2k privilege awarded for 1k accepted edits) or they could be awarded on a case-by-case basis (like the moderator elections but perhaps not on as large in scale and not sitewide... say, just here on meta (like tag burnination posts)... the user (or perhaps by someone else on their behalf, as a show of appreciation) would request a higher privilege via a meta post and after thorough background checks and enough votes from people here they will be manually upgraded to one step higher on the [privileges list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)).

I think this will have the following benefits:

- This will show appreciation for people who have relentlessly helped in the moderation effort and empower them with tools to create a greater impact. And will make reviewers *in general* to feel more appreciated on this site. Perhaps even bring back people who have given up on moderation.
- It will motivate other low reputation users to participate more in the moderation effort causing them to in turn learn more about how Stack Overflow works (less off-topic questions because they themselves know what is on-topic, etc).
- This will increase the total number of reviewers/editors/vote casters we have on the top of the *"food-chain"* (More people who can see deleted posts, more people who can cast close votes and so on).
- It will increase participation here on Meta.
- This won't affect the existing reputation system as no reputation is being awarded.
- Unlike moderators these users would have little to no pressure over them to use their newly awarded privileges. They could either use them or wear them as a badge and keep doing whatever they were doing.
- I feel that it is highly unlikely that such privileges will be misused because the people who put all this effort for no personal gain have the best of Stack Overflow in their minds.
- Any misuse of their awarded privileges could be raised here on meta by other users and would lead to the termination of their "elevated" status and the retraction of said privileges.

Some issues that I see with this idea:

- It will increase the workload on Meta.
- It might (well, you know it will) cause conflicts.
- It will require an entire set of guidelines to be put in place (like tag burnination) to decide who qualifies and who doesn't.
- It might not make any significant dent because such user are few and far between (although I still think that they should be rewarded in some way).

What are your views on this?

<sub><sub>Note: I am not asking this for myself. I have nowhere near that level of participation & effort. And I am neither that active nor *looking to be that active* with moderation. Also note that I mentioned Jeanne as an example (they are the best example I have) and they have no part in this. They might or might not have any interest in this proposal, I don't know. I haven't asked them.</sub></sub>

Comment: Users like Jeanne Dark should just run for moderator in a moderator election and earn the privileges the normal way.

Comment: Seems like an OK idea but I'm unsure if would apply to enough people to be really worth

Comment: Sadly, with the current state of the candidate score, and that the company is so backlogged that they can't get to any time soon, prevents low-rep users from having even a slight chance of winning. Rep and candidate score have almost always been an indicator of who wins - regardless of whether the candidate would make a good mod or not

Comment: This should also work the other way round. If a high rep-user repeatedly demonstrates that they don't understand community moderation, it should be possible to remove privileges. On some sites of the network there are users with > 250 000 rep who think that questions should be closed because the OP did not accept one of the answers.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz There's _mods_ on network sites that think that. Users and mods on SO generally know better (and those claims get solidly shut down by the community whenever there's complaints about it). I still agree, especially on a per-privilege basis. Would also offer us far more options beyond just suspending over repeated tool abuse

Comment: Biggest issue with this idea: It needs to be implemented by SO (and given the backlog, it's unlikely to happen). Currently there's no way to do this. Side-note: I always wonder if it's really possible to cast on average 70 down-votes per day without some automation.

Comment: @BDL when I was active on SO I used to easily cross the 100 vote limit everyday... and I was very consistent... so I'll say yes

Comment: @CodyGray Not everybody who does a lot of curating wants to be a mod or has the skill to be one.

Comment: A bit minor, but I would like to be able to deny certain privileges (mainly the dupe hammer, I think 1 out of 3 votes is impactful enough and more reliable). So far, the only possibility is to exclude answers from reputation/score in order to not achieve certain privileges.

Comment: Dupe hammering is a double-edged sword @MichaelSzczesny . I often find myself quick to hammer because I know that there are users in the tags I frequent who have a habit of answering questions with well-known canonical duplicates. Duplicate closure is there to help the OP find the answer quickly and to stop further duplicate answers.

Comment: @BillTürstandswithUkraine very much so. I am very active in a particular forum and do what I can to keep it clean, but I'd never want to be a moderator there. If only for how people change their behaviour around you, all of a sudden you're a "them" instead of a "we".

Comment: Who are you calling a "they", @Gimby?! Did I miss a memo that we were supposed to change our behavior?

Comment: Of course not, @Bill, that's why I've always believed it's critical that users nominate *themselves* for moderator. But I think there is also some stigma (perhaps highlighted by Gimby's comment?) surrounding the idea of moderator, which is unfortunate. Different moderators naturally take on different roles. Not everyone is the same. If your interest is curation, not handling sockpuppetry, for example, then there's still a place for you on the mod team. We need all types. As for Jeanne, the point of my comment was she undoubtedly has the skill to be a moderator, whether she'll admit it or not.

Comment: @CodyGray I was speaking specifically about that forum, but there is a little bit of that stigmatisation going on here as well as you probably know all too well. You become a moderator and you're pretty much immediately, in the eyes of especially people who are in a certain stage of upset, the source of everything that goes wrong and at the same time the solution to everything that goes wrong.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine given the small pool of candidates we've been trending toward, i'd say it's becoming more and more likely for low rep users to be elected despite the candidate score, they need only apply.

Comment: [Aggrieved poster's view of moderators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sg14jNbBb-8). Thank you for wearing a target and taking the hit for the team.

Comment: For what it's worth, Catija has mentioned this before as a cause she champions, and has worked on for some time in terms of how it might be implemented (specifically, changing certain privileges so they are use-gated rather than rep-gated). It may well come some day in the future but it's certainly something that will take a long time to get right... or at least make sure it isn't broken in ways that rep-gating is not.

Comment: @CodyGray 2021 election was early in October? Is 2022 delayed?